# Error-com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'BY'

Tags: java

```
private void UptadeSupplierActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{                                               
    try
    {
        Class.forName(driver);  
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rec =st.executeQuery("SELECT SupName, SupSurName" +
           "FROM Suppliers" +
           "ORDER BY SupName");

        while(rec.next())
        {
            System.out.println(rec.getString("SupName") + "," + rec.getString("SupSurName") + ".");
        }
        st.close();
    } 
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error-" + e.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: You miss blanks at the end of strings.

Comment: What does this have to do with JavaScript and jQuery?

Comment: i am really new to java what do you mean miss blank ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You concatenate your strings like this:

`"SELECT SupName, SupSurName" + "FROM SUPPLIERS"`

This will result into:

`SELECT SupName, SupSurNameFROM Suppiers`

Note that you are missing a space between "SupSurName" and "FROM". Either add a " " (space) between your strings or simply add a space to the end of each string.